# Ubuntu dual boot Yosemite issues

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

I'm running a dual boot (mac os/ubuntu-12.04) on my mac book pro. Yesterday I upgraded to Yosemite and the boot loader went to pot. I used rEFInd to reinstall using the following protocol-http://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-dual-boot-issue-with-yosemite-ubuntu/

When I start my system I now see rEFInd menu. Notably, I see 2x apple icons, 4 ubuntu icons and 1 penguin. The penguin icon says there's not bootable device. Only one of the ubuntu icons gives a promising result- it loads bunch of text and I hear the bongo sound, but no desktop screen just some text on dark screen. The remaining ubuntu icons load a bunch of text then to a blank screen.

So, I'm not sure what is going on?

1. Why so many icons for linux?
2. Should I reinstall grub using bootable CD?
3. Could the ubuntu icon that gives me the bongos be working-just need to install nvidia drivers using bootable CD?

Thanks,

MSB